# If Partial Duplicate on Line, Remove Line

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a file with 400+ lines, but some of the lines have partial duplicates. Below is a simplified version.

file.txt:

```
A_12_23 A_12_34 B_12_23 B_12_34
A_1_34 A_23_34 B_1_12 B_1_23
```

The fields are whitespace-separated where the letter before the first underscore is an identifier and the values after the first underscore are its values. A partial duplicate is one where one of the fields for A has the same values after the underscore as one of the B fields. The lines are sorted so that the A fields are always before the B fields.  There are no other identifiers.

What I would like to do is remove any line with a partial duplicate.

output.txt:

```
A_1_34 A_23_34 B_1_12 B_1_23
```

How would I go about doing this? I know how to remove exact duplicates on a line by:

```
awk '$1!=$2' file.txt > output.txt     # Can use various combinations if needed
```

I am not sure about about partial duplicates. For example: 12_23 is repeated two times on the first line, so I want it deleted. Stopping at deleting duplicated partial strings is okay since it will also delete if repeated more.

Please let me know how I can improve this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there are always 4 sets of numbers on a line, and you only care about comparing sets of numbers, you could use `awk -F'[AB ]'`, make an array for each row, and check if any previously added number is in the array, and if so don't output the row.

Comment: What do you mean by "partial duplicate"? `B_1` also occurs several times on the line you say you want to keep. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Good point @tripleee. I have updated the question. Let me know if it needs further clarification.

Comment: Will the A things always come before the B things? Are there C things and D things too? Are the things always separated by whitespace?

Comment: I have sorted the lines so that A is before B. There are only A or B. Each line also has two A and two B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly generalizing the answer by malarres, here is a regex which looks for any value after A which also occurs after B, followed by space or newline.  The number of digit groups in each field is arbitrary, but this does assume that all A values are before all B values, and that these tokens only occur at the beginning of a field.

```sh
grep -Ev 'A_([^_ ]+(_[^ _]+)*) (.* )?B_\1( |$)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `awk` you can use `grep` for that

`$ grep -v -E '._(.._..).*\1' file.txt`

`-v` to print lines NOT matching

`'._(.._..).*\1'`  looks for repetitions of the pattern `.._..`

Comment: This hardcodes an assumption that all the substrings the OP wants have groups of exactly two digits. But `grep -Ev 'A_([^_]+_[^_]+).*B\1'` would work for the updated requirement (provided the A groups always come before B, and with a chance for false positives if there are substring matches).

Comment: @tripleee yes. If the pattern of duplicate is different for sure the OP can modify it

Comment: `grep -Ev 'A_([^_ ]+_[^ _]+) (.*)?B\1|B_([^ _]+_[^ _]+) (.* )?A\3'` could work for arbitrary order and a slightly better anchoring to avoid false positives. This still assumes that there are exactly two groups of digits in each value.

Comment: Oh and of course no need to parenthesize the backref.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude first two characters of each field and check for duplicates, if not any, print the line. You can modify the last argument of `substr` to exlude any number of initial chars.

```
awk '{delete a; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[substr($i,3)]++) next} 1' file
```